# a post or the post?

Tags: grammar, articles

Which article should I use in the following sentence?

*'I couldn't help but make **A** post about it'*
or
*'I couldnt' help but make **THE** post about it'*

(It's the first sentence in the text.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you mean it's the first sentence of the text you are posting, use **a**. You can't call it **the post** if you are only just starting to write it. You had been thinking to yourself "I must make **a post** about that."

Answer (score 0):

'A post':  about any post you (or someone else) has made.

'I made a post about it' means that you have (in the past) made a post about it, but which specific post you are talking about is not important.  You have made one or many posts and you are not specifying which you are talking about.

'The post': about a unique, specific, or special post.

'I made the post about it' means you have made some specific post, and there was something unique or special about that post. It may have been the defining post that solves all confusion about that subject, or the post everyone references to show the flaws in your arguments on that subject. How it is special or unique is not defined, but using 'the' shows that it is.

Answer (score -2):

From Google:

> def·i·nite ar·ti·cle
> /ˈdef(ə)nət ˈärdəkəl/
> Learn to pronounce
> nounGRAMMAR
> plural noun: definite articles
> a determiner ( the in English) that introduces a noun phrase and implies that the thing mentioned has already been mentioned, or is common knowledge, or is about to be defined (as in the book on the table ; the art of government ; the famous poet and short story writer ).

If you're using "post" in an indefinite sense, you should use "a". If you're using it in a definite sense, you should use "the".